# How to create a flash website based on Drupal CMS?

Tags: flash, drupal

I used both flash and drupal for creating websites. Now what i will like to achieve is to create fully functional website in flash and use drupal for creating users, roles etc.
Does any one has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that will try to give you a short answer. First Thing. Real Flash CMS sites have other construction then templates in Drupal. Their 1-Page Application sends and get response data from a server. There are two ways to get what you want:

1. Create Drupal Template with flash for all Views: 1 view =  1 page with 1 flash template.
   Use flshVars (put there xml describing content) to tell flash what to do and what to show. If you have in template components/widgets/etc. you have choice:

   - Create Loader and load swf with component logic and to send data from Main Flash Template to a component. In optimistic situation you can use 1 swf with template to many views and just load needed swfs.
   - Have components inside flash template - in one swf file. In that situation you must create new swf for new view.

   Of course you can build View from xml (tell loader what to load, about it size, etc.) or make it "static" and let its parts to read data for xml.
2. Create 1-site Application. In this case you must litle modify a drupal. It's simple to 1.1 point but:

   - You have 1 page for all views.
   - You only get xml for new views.
   - Main App View process xml to create site.
   - In this case you must now API like said ceejayoz

That is all in short. Sorry for the typos - I had to hurry.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to have Drupal function essentially as an API. The [Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services) can help.

Comment: The Drupal-Flash site that looms largest in my mind is the Digital Dollhouse (http://www.digitaldollhouse.com/). I believe they used Services in this fashion. Perhaps the Case Study (http://drupal.org/node/430222) would provide some hints?